# NoReverseMatch at /rango/ newbie got stuck in tango w django tutorial

Tags: django

The error message debug mode:

> NoReverseMatch at /rango/ Reverse for 'category' with arguments '('other-frameworks',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['rango/category/(?P\w+)/$'] Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/rango/ Django Version: 1.7.4 Exception Type: NoReverseMatch Exception Value: Reverse for 'category' with arguments '('other-frameworks',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['rango/category/(?P\w+)/$'] Exception Location: C:\Users\Beheerder\Desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 468 Python Executable: C:\Users\Beheerder\Desktop\venv\Scripts\python.exe Python Version:
>   3.4.2

Error during template rendering

> Reverse for 'category' with arguments '('other-frameworks',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['rango/category/(?P\w+)/$']

```
1   {% if cats %}
2       <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
3       {% for c in cats %}
4           <li><a href="{% url 'category'  c.slug %}">{{ c.name }}</a></li>
5       {% endfor %}
6   
7   {% else %}
8       <li> <strong >There are no category present.</strong></li>
9   
10      </ul>
11  {% endif %}
```

I ( as a newbie ) have no idea what is going wrong here,

This is the link to the specific tutorial part: http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from rango import views

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
        url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='about'),
        url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_url>\w+)/$', views.category, name='category'),
        url(r'^add_category/$', views.add_category, name='add_category'),
        url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>\w+)/add_page/$', views.add_page, name='add_page'),
        url(r'^restricted/$', views.restricted, name='restricted'),
        url(r'^add_page/$', views.add_page, name="add_page"),
        )
```

Comment: can u post ur urls.py

Answer (score 2):

The `-` dash in the `other-frameworks` string does not match the (alphanumeric and underscore) `\w`.

Change the regex in the url to the `[\w-]+`:

```
url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_url>[\w-]+)/$', views.category,
                                                  name='category'),
```